# Is there a valid way to use number values in templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the situation where I need to split a number of bitset blocks in half.  Is there a way to merge the following two functions into something resembling the third?  Having something like the third feels more right and general.

```
pair<bitset<32>, bitset<32> > 
split_block_in_half(
  bitset<64> block
){
  bitset<block.size()> filter;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < filter.size()/2; ++i){
    filter.set(i);
  }

  return make_pair<bitset<block.size()/2>, bitset<block.size()/2> >(
    bitset<block.size()/2>(((block ^ (filter << (block.size()/2))) >> (block.size()/2)).to_ulong()),
    bitset<block.size()/2>((block ^ filter).to_ulong())
  );
}


pair<bitset<28>, bitset<28> > 
split_block_in_half(
  bitset<56> block
){
  bitset<block.size()> filter;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < filter.size()/2; ++i){
    filter.set(i);
  }

  return make_pair<bitset<block.size()/2>, bitset<block.size()/2> >(
bitset<block.size()/2>(((block ^ (filter << (block.size()/2))) >> (block.size()/2)).to_ulong()),
bitset<block.size()/2>((block ^ filter).to_ulong())
  );
}



template<
  typename N>
pair<bitset<N>, bitset<N> >
split_block_in_half(
  bitset<2*N> block
){
  bitset<block.size()> filter;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < filter.size()/2; ++i){
    filter.set(i);
  }

  return make_pair<bitset<block.size()/2>, bitset<block.size()/2> >(
    bitset<block.size()/2>(((block ^ (filter << (block.size()/2))) >> (block.size()/2)).to_ulong()),
    bitset<block.size()/2>((block ^ filter).to_ulong())
  );
}
```

Is there a clever compile time way to merge the two separate functions above, or is this unsupported?

Comment: `template <int N>`

Comment: On the one hand it's supertrivial and basic, just asking if a language feature exists, and it does. On the other hand it can be useful to googlers coming here. Don't know whether to vote to close.

Comment: First comment solved it.  I tried searching, but without being a master of templates I don't know enough to find out.  I'd guess leave it up for future googlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an integer value in template parameter:

```
template <int N>
pair<bitset<N>, bitset<N>> 
split_block_in_half(
    bitset<2*N> block
)
......
```

The downside is that, since `2*N` cannot be deduced from function calls, you need to explicitly specify N:

```
split_block_in_half<28>(block); // where block is bitset<56>
```

---

If you define it like this, you can use SFINAE to restrict that N be even.

```
template <int N>
std::enable_if_t<
    N % 2 == 0,
    pair<bitset<N/2>, bitset<N/2>>
>
split_block_in_half(bitset<N>);
```

If you don't have C++14, change `std::enable_if_t<>` to `typename std::enable_if<>::type` (C++11).

Comment: Now, this gets the code to compile without error if the function is not used.  When using it in the way described, template deduction fails.

Comment: @Josh No, you shouldn't do `bitset<block.size()>`. You must do `bitset<2*N>`, i.e., compile-time constant.

Comment: It looks like the "2*N" portion runs afoul of non-deduced contexts section 3.  However, this doesn't cleanly capture that block's size should be even.  Maybe for a later standard.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Could you update your answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: The function is intended to split an even length bitset into a pair of equal length bitsets.  This can't be captured by deduction unless I can specify the length of the input as "2*N" in order to make sure the input block length is even.  Else it can be subject to odd input lengths and rounding errors.

Comment: "*`2*N` cannot be deduced from function calls*" - what about something like this instead? `template <int N> pair<bitset<N/2>, bitset<N/2>> split_block_in_half( bitset<N> &block )` and then use SFINAE to make sure it works only when `N` is even

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you be a bit more specific? How to enforce that `N` is even? With `static_assert`?

Comment: @iBug that will work, but I was thinking `std::enable_if` instead

Comment: That is better than what I went with.  I ended up using a static_assert().  I'll update to this later today.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a full working example that doesn't require specifying `N`. I implemented the logic a bit differently. I assume the goal is to have the pair's `first` member contain the high order bits and have `second` contain the low order bits. Do be aware that `^` is the [logical XOR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_logic) operation, though it may resemble the logical AND sometimes used in propositional logic.

```
template<size_t N>
pair<bitset<N/2>, bitset<N/2>> split_block_in_half(const bitset<N>& block){
    static_assert(N % 2 == 0 && N != 0, "N must be even and non-zero");
    pair<bitset<N/2>, bitset<N/2>> ret;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N/2; ++i){
        ret.first[i] = block[i + N/2];
        ret.second[i] = block[i];
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {

    bitset<64> bs { 0x1234567887654321 };

    auto halves = split_block_in_half(bs);

    std::cout << std::hex
        << halves.first.to_ullong() << '\n'
        << halves.second.to_ullong() << '\n';

    // prints:
    // > 12345678
    // > 87654321

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest passing in `block` by const reference